# Is "much" necessary before "to the annoyance of"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases

> Frank started singing along, (much) to the annoyance of Ellen.

Is "much" necessary here or is it OK to leave it out?

Comment: No, it isn't necessary; it just makes Ellen sound _more_ annoyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave it out, *much* just stresses the intensity or degree of the emotion/feeling/state.

Similarly, *much* is optional in the following idioms:

> (Much) *to my horror*, I looked up and saw the man standing in his yard.

> (Much) *to my surprise*, they offered me a £4,000 scholarship.

> I applied for the job, and, (much) *to my amazement*, I was hired.

Comment: 'Much' stresses the the intensity or degree of the feeling. In "to the annoyance of (someone)" the degree of annoyance is left unspecified. A person might be slightly annoyed or very annoyed.